# Is this answer worthy of undeleting?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

### With great power comes great responsibility

I read this unanswered question: [Triple monitor on Nvidia and Intel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577960/triple-monitor-on-nvidia-and-intel) and found the [answer written by *yilmi*](https://askubuntu.com/a/578447/) was deleted.

[image: Deleted answer]

Although I've had protect/un-protect powers for awhile now I've never used them. Now I have delete/un-delete powers also never used. I would like to get input on if the aforementioned answer is a good one to undelete.

I appreciate the answer might qualify as "abandoned" because *yilmi* has not signed on in 17 months. On one hand this means: *"why bother wasting time"*. But on the other hand it means: *"you probably won't ruffle many feathers"*.

**PS** I can see the answer was deleted by *Mitch* but I can't see any comments by him on why it was deleted. You would think with delete powers comes the ability to give a reason why it was deleted?

Comment: Just to make a note... this was before my time as a moderator here, *but* I found evidence the answer you're referencing was removed along with multiple duplicate posts of the same exact answer by the user back in 2015.

Comment: Noticed that one of the linked questions got an answer that was accepted later [Can X.org Load Two Different Drivers? (Triple-Head Setup with Intel and NVidia Card)](//askubuntu.com/q/280651) so I've voted to close the question you've linked to and the other unanswered one as duplicates of that one since to me they all seem to be asking for the same thing

Comment: @Zanna Excellent. I've voted along with you. The question is 3 years old and it's nice to tidy up old unanswered questions this way.

Answer (score 10):

Alas, you don't have the power to vote to undelete that post, despite your hard earned 20k Trusted User privilege. If you try, you'll get a message saying

> A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted

(I've tried this multiple times and I'm always disappointed)

<sub>Even if you could, it would take 3 20k-ers' votes to undelete. I've never managed to get anything undeleted without deliberately enlisting support in chat or with flags - people just don't look at the [delete page](https://askubuntu.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=last7days) in the mod tools.</sub>

So the only solution is to flag it for mod attention like any other humble flag-wielder and explain why you think it should be undeleted. Personally I'm not sure (maybe this post is NAA because I don't know the answer to your question!) - I don't think `xrandr` works with nvidia drivers...

Comment: Ahhh just my luck. The first time I think of using the `undelete` button it turns out it's a magic wand that ran out of gas.

Comment: In fact `xrandr` works with NVidia drivers for such things , despite NVidia drivers have a couple of other terrible problems.

Comment: I tried to flag my answer to undelete it, I ended up getting downvotes in my other answers, so whenever I have an answer deleted my a moderator I just give up .

Comment: @Melchia do you think the downvotes are related?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Bottom of the line I moved on. https://i.imgur.com/8HCzZZy.png check this there are even answers with 100 votes deleted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top